# Set linewidth and facecolor of an AnchoredOffsetbox?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to change the linewidth, facecolor, etc. of an AnchoredOffsetbox?

I've used this to list some variables next to my plot (like 'A=1', 'B=2'), in such a way that the '=' are aligned vertically, so it's a bit like an extra legend (but the handles are also text). But I can't figure out how to set the properties of the frame like you can for a legend.

Any tips are much appreciated!

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredOffsetbox, TextArea, HPacker, VPacker

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(3,3))
ax = plt.subplot(111)

p_txt0 = ['A = ', 'BBB = ']
p_num0 = [1.0, 2.0]
p_txt = [TextArea(text, textprops=dict(size='medium',weight='bold')) 
         for text in p_txt0]
p_num = [TextArea('%6.2f' % num, textprops=dict(size='medium',weight='bold')) 
         for num in p_num0]
p_vbox_txt = VPacker(children=p_txt, align="right", pad=0, sep=5)
p_vbox_num = VPacker(children=p_num, align="right", pad=0, sep=5)
box = HPacker(children=[p_vbox_txt,p_vbox_num], align="center", pad=5, sep=3)

parambox = AnchoredOffsetbox(loc=2, child=box, pad=0.0, frameon=True, 
                             borderpad=0.0, bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.0), 
                             bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)

parambox.set_clip_on(False) #so box won't be cut off when saving
ax.add_artist(parambox)

plt.savefig('offsetbox.png', bbox_extra_artists=(parambox,), bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: example]

Comment: Can you include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sure, I've added a code example now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can access your `parambox` patch, and set properties on that:

Before `ax.add_artist`, try these lines:

```
parambox.patch.set_linewidth(4)
parambox.patch.set_edgecolor('r')
parambox.patch.set_facecolor('g')
```

[image]

I think this is setting the properties of the underlying `matplotlib.patches.Patch`, so you can look [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch) for more options of things you can change (e.g. `set_alpha`, `set_linestyle`).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!