# How do I change the "str" ​labels in a function to "int" and return a plt.legend() that concatenates the two labels in an "int, str" format?

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, label, pca

I have a function that allows me to display the circle of correlations of my pca.

The problem with this function is that the labels of my variables (column names) prevent me from reading my results correctly.
To overcome this problem, I have to insert a line of code before my function to associate numbers with the labels of the variables (of the df used to make my pca):

```py
n_labels = [value for value in range(1, (len(df.columns) + 1))]
```

I tried unsuccessfully to insert this line in my function:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def display_circles(pcs,
                    n_comp,
                    pca,
                    axis_ranks,
                    labels=None,
                    label_rotation=0,
                    lims=None):
    for d1, d2 in axis_ranks:  # We display the first 3 factorial planes, so the first 6 components
        if d2 < n_comp:

            # figure initialization
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))

            # determination of graph limits
            if lims is not None:
                xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = lims
            elif pcs.shape[1] < 30:
                xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = -1, 1, -1, 1
            else:
                xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = min(pcs[d1, :]), max(pcs[d1, :]), min(
                    pcs[d2, :]), max(pcs[d2, :])

            # arrow display
            # if there are more than 30 arrows, the triangle is not displayed at their end
            if pcs.shape[1] < 30:
                plt.quiver(np.zeros(pcs.shape[1]),
                           np.zeros(pcs.shape[1]),
                           pcs[d1, :],
                           pcs[d2, :],
                           angles='xy',
                           scale_units='xy',
                           scale=1,
                           color="grey")
            else:
                lines = [[[0, 0], [x, y]] for x, y in pcs[[d1, d2]].T]
                ax.add_collection(
                    LineCollection(lines, axes=ax, alpha=.1, color='black'))

            # display of variable names
            if labels is not None:
                for i, (x, y) in enumerate(pcs[[d1, d2]].T):
                    if x >= xmin and x <= xmax and y >= ymin and y <= ymax:
                        plt.text(x,
                                 y,
                                 labels[i],
                                 fontsize='22',
                                 ha='center',
                                 va='bottom',
                                 rotation=label_rotation,
                                 color="red",
                                 alpha=0.7)

            # circle display
            circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, facecolor='none', edgecolor='b')
            plt.gca().add_artist(circle)

            # setting graph limits
            plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
            plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)

            # display of horizontal and vertical lines
            plt.plot([-1, 1], [0, 0], color='grey', ls='--')
            plt.plot([0, 0], [-1, 1], color='grey', ls='--')

            # names of the axes, with the percentage of inertia explained
            plt.xlabel('F{} ({}%)'.format(
                d1 + 1, round(100 * pca.explained_variance_ratio_[d1], 1)),
                       fontsize=14)
            plt.ylabel('F{} ({}%)'.format(
                d2 + 1, round(100 * pca.explained_variance_ratio_[d2], 1)),
                       fontsize=14)

            plt.title("Circle of correlations (F{} and F{})".format(
                d1 + 1, d2 + 1),
                      size=24)
            plt.show()
```

This is how I call my function:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import decomposition, preprocessing


# Here a dataset for the example:
column_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8]
column_2 = [4, 2, 9, 23, 3, 52, 41, 4]
column_3 = [9, 8, 7, 6, 6, 9, 24, 11]
column_4 = [45, 36, 74, 35, 29, 45, 29, 39]
column_5 = [35, 84, 3, 54, 68, 78, 65, 97]
column_6 = [24, 96, 7, 54, 67, 69, 88, 95]
column_7 = [5, 39, 72, 42, 22, 41, 24, 41]
column_8 = [30, 98, 8, 67, 68, 41, 27, 87]


df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1': column_1,
                  'column_2': column_2,
                  'column_3': column_3, 
                  'column_4': column_4,
                  'column_5': column_5,
                  'column_6': column_6,
                  'column_7': column_7, 
                  'column_8': column_8})


pca_data = preprocessing.scale(df)

pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components = 8)
pca.fit(pca_data)

# We set the number of components
n_comp = 2
# Recovery of the components of the pca object
pcs = pca.components_
# We label a number to each column name
n_labels = [value for value in range(1, (len(df.columns) + 1))]
display_circles(pcs, n_comp, pca, [(0, 1), (0, 2)], labels=n_labels)

for element in zip(n_labels, df.columns):
    print(element)
```

Here is my obtained result:
[image: Circle of correlations]

**Edit 1**: that i would like (*UPD: with the answer of @Stef -Thanks you very much and congratulations for this solution-*)

it's almost perfect but the problem is when I use this function:

```py
n_comp = 3
pcs = pca.components_
# I always have to write this line to get a label number
n_labels=[value for value in range(1,(len(list_candidates.columns)+1))]
display_circles(pcs, n_comp, pca, [(0, 1), (0, 2)], labels=n_labels)
```

on my real dataframe, this throws me two problems:

1. I still have to include the line

```py
n_labels=[value for value in range(1,(len(list_candidates.columns)+1))]
```

to obtain a label number instead of the name of my variables.

2. I get the error message *"NameError: name 'df' is not defined"* when running

```py
display_circles(pcs, n_comp, pca, [(0, 1), (0, 2)], labels=n_labels)
```

So I'm looking to define my `display_circles()` function so that when I set the `labels="name_of_the_df"` argument it returns me the same result as

```py
n_labels=[value for value in range(1,(len("name_of_the_df".columns)+1))]
```

plus a `plt.legend()` like the one made by @Steph (thanks)

To get this (desired) result:

[image: Circle of correlations that i want]

I also have to modify "name_of_the_df" in the function definition:

```
   #legend
   plt.legend(n_labels,
              candidate_list.columns,
              handler_map={int: IntHandler()},
              bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
```

Comment: do you want the legend to be printed out by `display_circles()` on the figure?

Comment: Yes, but outside, to the right of the figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own [legend handler](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_handler_api.html?highlight=legend_artist#matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerBase.legend_artist) for integers:

```
from matplotlib.text import Text

class IntHandler:
    def legend_artist(self, legend, orig_handle, fontsize, handlebox):
        x0, y0 = handlebox.xdescent, handlebox.ydescent
        text = Text(x0, y0, str(orig_handle), color='red')
        handlebox.add_artist(text)
        return text
```

and then call

```
plt.legend(n_labels, df.columns, handler_map={int: IntHandler()}, bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
```

before `plt.show()` in `display_circles`:

[image]

---

Full example as per comment below and edited question:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.text import Text
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import decomposition, preprocessing

class IntHandler:
    def legend_artist(self, legend, orig_handle, fontsize, handlebox):
        x0, y0 = handlebox.xdescent, handlebox.ydescent
        text = Text(x0, y0, str(orig_handle), color='red')
        handlebox.add_artist(text)
        return text

def display_circles(pcs,
                    n_comp,
                    pca,
                    axis_ranks,
                    labels=None,
                    label_rotation=0,
                    lims=None):
    if labels == None:
        labels = range(1, len(pca.feature_names_in_) + 1)
    
    for d1, d2 in axis_ranks:  # We display the first 3 factorial planes, so the first 6 components
        if d2 < n_comp:

            # figure initialization
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))

            # determination of graph limits
            if lims is not None:
                xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = lims
            elif pcs.shape[1] < 30:
                xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = -1, 1, -1, 1
            else:
                xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = min(pcs[d1, :]), max(pcs[d1, :]), min(
                    pcs[d2, :]), max(pcs[d2, :])

            # arrow display
            # if there are more than 30 arrows, the triangle is not displayed at their end
            if pcs.shape[1] < 30:
                plt.quiver(np.zeros(pcs.shape[1]),
                           np.zeros(pcs.shape[1]),
                           pcs[d1, :],
                           pcs[d2, :],
                           angles='xy',
                           scale_units='xy',
                           scale=1,
                           color="grey")
            else:
                lines = [[[0, 0], [x, y]] for x, y in pcs[[d1, d2]].T]
                ax.add_collection(
                    LineCollection(lines, axes=ax, alpha=.1, color='black'))

            # display of variable names
            if labels is not None:
                for i, (x, y) in enumerate(pcs[[d1, d2]].T):
                    if x >= xmin and x <= xmax and y >= ymin and y <= ymax:
                        plt.text(x,
                                 y,
                                 labels[i],
                                 fontsize='22',
                                 ha='center',
                                 va='bottom',
                                 rotation=label_rotation,
                                 color="red",
                                 alpha=0.7,
                        )

            # circle display
            circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, facecolor='none', edgecolor='b')
            plt.gca().add_artist(circle)

            # setting graph limits
            plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
            plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)

            # display of horizontal and vertical lines
            plt.plot([-1, 1], [0, 0], color='grey', ls='--')
            plt.plot([0, 0], [-1, 1], color='grey', ls='--')

            # names of the axes, with the percentage of inertia explained
            plt.xlabel('F{} ({}%)'.format(
                d1 + 1, round(100 * pca.explained_variance_ratio_[d1], 1)),
                       fontsize=14)
            plt.ylabel('F{} ({}%)'.format(
                d2 + 1, round(100 * pca.explained_variance_ratio_[d2], 1)),
                       fontsize=14)

            plt.title("Circle of correlations (F{} and F{})".format(
                d1 + 1, d2 + 1),
                      size=24)

            plt.legend(labels,
                       pca.feature_names_in_,
                       handler_map={int: IntHandler()},
                       bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
            
            plt.show()



# Here a dataset for the example:
column_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8]
column_2 = [4, 2, 9, 23, 3, 52, 41, 4]
column_3 = [9, 8, 7, 6, 6, 9, 24, 11]
column_4 = [45, 36, 74, 35, 29, 45, 29, 39]
column_5 = [35, 84, 3, 54, 68, 78, 65, 97]
column_6 = [24, 96, 7, 54, 67, 69, 88, 95]
column_7 = [5, 39, 72, 42, 22, 41, 24, 41]
column_8 = [30, 98, 8, 67, 68, 41, 27, 87]


df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1': column_1,
                  'column_2': column_2,
                  'column_3': column_3, 
                  'column_4': column_4,
                  'column_5': column_5,
                  'column_6': column_6,
                  'column_7': column_7, 
                  'column_8': column_8})


pca_data = preprocessing.scale(df)

pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components = 8)
pca.fit(pd.DataFrame(pca_data, columns=df.columns))

# We set the number of components
n_comp = 2
# Recovery of the components of the pca object
pcs = pca.components_

display_circles(pcs, n_comp, pca, [(0, 1), (0, 2)])
```

Comment: How do you get that result? I mean how do you call that function?

Comment: Yeah, i mean if i called the function with ```n_comp = 2
pcs = pca.components_
display_circles(pcs, n_comp, pca, [(0, 1), (0, 2)], labels=df.columns)``` it return the circle with the name of the columns, not the number.

Comment: the question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634522/set-linewidth-and-facecolor-of-an-anchoredoffsetbox) does something similar

Comment: @ElMeTeOr: I have simplified the answer by using a proper legend and placed it next to the axes as you added in the comment to the question.

Comment: @Stef again thank you, I explain in more detail what I expect taking into account your answer, it's almost perfect. I made an **edit 1** in my question.

Comment: My bad, `df` was by chance visible as a global variable and I used it inside `display_circles`. You can pass the column names implicitely in the `pca` object and then retrieve them inside `display_circles` using `feature_names_in_`. To do so you must call `fit` with a dataframe instead of an array. See my edit under the horizontal line for a full working example.

Comment: @Stef great it work, thank you for your time, you teached me a lot here!  I left the line with the ```n_labels```, you're right I was bored more than anything else, I can choose to leave the variable names or not by keeping this method.